# Merge child records

Tags: apex, app-development

I am merging contact records using standard Merge from account.

I have a related object on contact called "Allocation". Assume i have 1 alocation record each in both the contacts. No when i merge the 2 contacts, it is created 2 Allocations(duplicate) on nerged contact record.

How do we handle these "Allocations" on merge, My requirement is if both the allocation records have same name, i have to create only 1 allocation on contact merge.

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to write a trigger to detect the merge (`after delete` where `MasterRecordId` is not null in records in `Trigger.old`) to also delete/merge any duplicate child objects you're interested in taking care of.